# Intercepting methods only when a specific class calls in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a scenario here and thought of getting advise on how it can be done.

Let's say I have method in a class called **class A** and this method is triggered by an instance of **Class A** in both **class B** and **class C**. How can I just intercept the method when it's triggered by just **class B** in Spring AOP.

Cheers,
Thiagz

Comment: As I can see it, there is no way to only intercept if the caller is B, but you could intercept everything, check to see what class did call your method and log something if it was called by B.

Comment: This is StackOverflow and SO ist about code. With all due respect, is it so hard to provide sample code instead of ambiguously trying to describe the problem in an abstract way in prose? Please update the question with a self-consistent, executable code sample illustrating the problem at hand, ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You will get much better help then, especially if you like to get help from me. `:-)` I think I can help you, but do not like to guess what exactly you might want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept with expression similar to below 
`@Around("@annotation(someAnnotation) && execution(* x.y.z.ClassB.*(..))")`

Apply this to method of **ClassA** to be intercepted - the magic you are looking forward to lies in the `execution` condition.

Although I haven't tried this but hope it helps!

Comment: I think the @annotation will not work for my scenario because I want to set condition on an incoming request, not on the class that I want intercept.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible but if you need this for very good business needs it is not hard to achieve. Just create **ClassD** with a method **delegate** which in turn will call the **ClassA** method. Then make **ClassB** only call **classB.delegate()** whereas **ClassC** will keep going straight to **ClassA**. Then you move the `@Around` annotation from **ClassA** to **ClassD.delegate()**

Don't forget to put a comment in **ClassD** explaining why this was needed to avoid others scrapping their heads :-)